# How to define linearity correctly

Tags: function-construction

I want to define a linear function, but I'm having problems when its arguments are not explicit sums:

```
f[a___ A]:= a f[A]
f[a___ B]:= a f[B]
f[a_Plus]:= Distribute @ Unevaluated @ f[a]
```

With this I get:

```
f[a A + b B]
(* a f[A] + b f[B] *)
```

But

```
f[c (A + B)]
(* f[(A + B) c]*)
```

What's the correct way to define it?

Comment: As a starting point, check the FullForm of your expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities.  Here's one

```
f[a_ b_] /; FreeQ[a, A | B] := a f[b]
```

I would also change

```
f[a_Plus] := Distribute @ Unevaluated @ f[a]
```

to the simpler

```
f[a_Plus] := f /@ a
```